# Convert between timezones and daylightsavings

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm sending date and time, separated, with javascript to a server:

```
var date = $("#txtDate").toISOString();
var time = $("#txtTime").toISOString();
```

I get both objects in server side, but my server has a different timezone than mine and is offset by an hour. So decided to convert timezones:

```
var timeToSave = date.AddHours(time.Hours).addMinutes(time.Minutes);
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");    
var newDateTime = TimeZoneinfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeToSave, timeZone);
```

That was working well until last sunday when daylight savings time ended in my timezone, and I got an hour offset again.

I realized the "timezone" class has a method to know if "datetime" is on daylight savings (IsDaylightSavingtime) but this method always return true no matter what datetime I send as param.

```
if (timeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(newDateTime))
{
    timeToSave = timeToSave.AddHours(-1);
}
```

How I can fix it?

Thanks.

Update:

Following the answer by Matt Johnson I was able to add time to date using the momentjs library and send it server side. This is what the new code looks like:

```
//javascript

//this return a moment object
var dateMoment = row.find(".txtDate").data('DateTimePicker').getDate(); 
//this return a moment object too
var timeMoment = row.find(".txtTime").data('DateTimePicker').getDate();  

//This object I send to server side
var dateToSend = dateMoment.add(timeMoment.format('HH'), 'hours').add(timeMoment.format('mm'), 'minutes');
```

Then in server side I do the conversion between timezones

```
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");

var dateTimeToSave = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(datetimeFromJS.ToUniversalTime(), timeZone);
```

But I still have an hour offset, I need to have the same date and time the user inputs.

Comment: Is the date and time provided by Javascript definitely a UTC time?

Comment: Send all datetime instances as UTC and receive all datetime instances as UTC. Is this a Web API or something else?

Comment: This is the sort of thing NodaTime can handle.  You might consider looking at its documentation.

Comment: What is the platform  for the server end? Is it Web API? MVC? Asp.Net web forms? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, my platform is Asp.net web forms, I just try with NodaTime but I had the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `IsDaylightSavingTime` to decide whether to add or subtract an hour yourself.  That work is already being done by the `ConvertTimeFromUtc` method.

Despite the name, `"Mountain Standard Time"` here *does* already account for daylight saving.  It is inclusive of both MST and MDT, with North American transitions (such as Denver).

The likely source of problem is with this:

```
// client-side JS
var date = $("#txtDate").toISOString();
var time = $("#txtTime").toISOString();

// server-side C#
var timeToSave = date.AddHours(time.Hours).addMinutes(time.Minutes);
```

Instead of sending date and time to the server separately, combine them on the client-side *before* converting to UTC.  Then you won't need to add them together on the server-side.

In other words, you can't reliably convert from local to UTC with date-only or time-only data.

#### Update

Based on your edit, (and I believe the function on the date-picker is `date()` not `getDate()`), you should change your client-side code to:

```
var dateToSend = moment(dateMoment).hour(timeMoment.hour()).minute(timeMoment.minute());
var utcString = dateToSend.toISOString();
```

Do not call `.ToUniversalTime()` on the server-side code.  The value you receive is *already* in universal time ([as converted by the `toISOString()` function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/)).

Comment: If you can be more specific about what `$("#txtDate")` and `$("#txtTime")` are, I can probably show you how to combine the data properly.  It's confusing because you're treating them as `Date` objects, but they appear to be named as text-box controls.  Perhaps you have some date/time picker controls attached?  Please explain.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I summarized it because I did not think it was the problem but they are a jquery plugin for date and time, my website has an input for date and other for time. I feel is a little difficult to manage datetime in javascrip side.   

Update:
This is the plugin [link](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.  Thanks.